# Questions on Lorentz generators in Spinor-Helicity formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, spinors, research-level, helicity

I have read the following PSE posts on Lorentz generators in Spinor-Helicity formalism:

1. [Total Angular Momentum Operator in Spinor-Helicity formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783821/)
2. [Derivation of conformal generators in spinor helicity formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289997/)

and I am also reading the notes titled as [Scattering Amplitudes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697), by Elvang and Huang. I have learnt that I can ''decompose'' (I say decompose because I imagine procecting onto spin indices $\{a,b\}$ first, and then onto $\{\dot{a},\dot{b}\}$ last) the angular momentum operator in a massless QFT as follows:

$$M_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow M_{ab}= \frac{i}{8}\epsilon_{cb}
(\sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}-\sigma^{\nu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu})_a^{\ \ c}
M_{\mu\nu}\\
M_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \tilde{M}_{\dot{a}\dot{b}}= \frac{i}{8}\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{c}}
(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu}-\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}\sigma^{\mu})^{\dot{c}}_{\ \ \dot{b}}
M_{\mu\nu}$$
where $M_{\mu\nu}=p_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}-p_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}$, and $\partial_{\mu}=\partial/\partial p^{\mu}$. Here, I am using the conventions in [Scattering Amplitudes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697).

**My first question:** $M_{\mu\nu}$ is the orbital angular momentum operator. Is there a corresponding mapping between the Spin angular momentum operator? I.e. something of the form

$$S_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow S_{ab}=\frac{i}{8}\epsilon_{cb}
(\sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}-\sigma^{\nu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu})_a^{\ \ c}
S_{\mu\nu}\\
S_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \tilde{S}_{\dot{a}\dot{b}}= \frac{i}{8}\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{c}}
(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu}-\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}\sigma^{\mu})^{\dot{c}}_{\ \ \dot{b}}
S_{\mu\nu}$$
if yes, then what is $S_{\mu\nu}$? If not, why is there no analogue for the spin angular momentum operator? Shouldn't there be one in order to define the total angular momentum operator, since $J_{\mu\nu}=L_{\mu\nu}+S_{\mu\nu}$?

In addition, the helicity is defined by
$$h=\sum_i \Big(
|i\rangle^{\dot{a}} \partial_{|i\rangle^{\dot{a}}}-
|i]_a \partial_{|i]_a}
\Big)$$
if I am not mistaken (no supersymmetric theories here).

**My second question:** how do I go from the known definition $h=\vec{\Sigma}\cdot \hat{p}$, where $\vec{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma^1,\sigma^2,\sigma^3)$, and $\vec{p}=\frac{1}{E}(p^x,p^y,p^z)$, to this definition? Is there a way?

Any help will be appreciated.